# DDD Как правильно выделить агрегаты и сущности

Tags: ddd

Помогите пожалуйста составить корректное видение архитектуры.
Разрабатывается платформа для обучения. Имеются следующие понятия:

- Папка (Категория)
- Курс
- Тема
- Урок
- Тест

Присутствует линейная вложенность от начала к концу списка:

- В Папке может быть много курсов (может и не быть)
- В Курсах может быть много тем (может и не быть)
- В Темах может быть много уроков (может и не быть)
- В Уроках может быть много тестов (может и не быть)

В теории корневым агрегатом выступает Папка (категория) и без её наличия ничего нижестоящего быть не может. В то же время, например, Тесты могут обладать своими свойствами, например список пользователей, которые их прошли. И получается, во первых, сущность ссылается на агрегат, а во вторых чтобы управлять всеми вложенными сущностями в Папку нужно очень много методов добавить в агрегат.
И вот я не пойму как правильно разбить эту цепочку.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Было решено сделать каждый из элементов самостоятельным агрегатом, а каждый вышестоящий просто содержит набор идентификаторов нижестоящего уровня.
Это помогло сделать их независимыми и добавлять конфигурирование на любой из этих уровней независимо.
И получается, что внутри своего ограниченного контекста они обособлены, но входят в связь с другим контекстом.
Возможно это не самое лучшее решение поскольку с точки зрения архитектуры на один и тот же уровень могут ссылаться другие, что неправильно. Но ничего лучше не было придумано